# shotwell restore missing files

Tags: shotwell

I am using shotwell 0.23.1.

I have a large library of photos which took me a day to import into shotwell.
After launching it again next day I forgot to mount my network share before hand. Shotwell reacted with placing all photos into "Missing files".

So I closed Shotwell, mounted the network drive, and launched Shotwell again. To my surprise it didn't put the photos back into the library, even though they are obviously not missing anymore.

How can I fix this? Do I have to re-import all photos again? Or is there an easy way to tell shotwell that these photos are not missing anymore?

Comment: Is the network drive the default photo directory for Shotwell, and if yes, have you enabled the "Watch library directory for new files" option? If both answers are yes the problem should resolve itself.

Comment: Hi Tom, the network drive is the default photo directory and the "Watch library directory for new files" is checked. But nothing happens. A black screen which says "No photos/videos" is all that is shown.

Comment: I used sqllite to check the photo.db. In the table phototable I changed flags from 8 into 0. That made all photos reappear again in the Library, so no more Missing files. Sad thing is that all tags seem to be gone, at least in the shotwell database. Hmmm.

Comment: Aha, now I understand how shotwell works: when it starts it checks the Library for any missing files. When a file cannot be found it changes the flag number to 8, and it removes the id from the image from the tagtable field photo_id_list (the id is in the format "thumb<number>", where <number is the id of the record in the phototable padded with 0 until it is 16 long, e.g. thumb0000000000000001).

Comment: This basically means that Missing files will never have any tags. I think that is a bad design decision. It would be more logical if these tags are only removed when you actually remove the file from the Missing files list, and not before hand. Now it is impossible to restore the shotwell database, including tags, when you had a one time glitch in your network connection to the Library.

Comment: I think Shotwell's behaviour here is the expected result. You pointed it at a library and then removed the library, and it faithfully followed your preference to watch that library for changes. To avoid metadata loss due to human error, have Shotwell write the tags, titles, and other metadata to photo files (It's another Preferences setting) and **make regular backups**. Otherwise you will face the exact same problem when your network drive dies.

Comment: Hi Tom, that is exactly what I do: Shotwell writes tags etc to the photo files. So the metadata itself isn't lost. It is just removed from the Shotwell database. The images themselves are NOT removed from the Shotwell database, they are flagged "missing". They only thing that *is* removed from the database are the tags.
That is why I am puzzled: the Shotwell behaviour in this instance is not consistent.